# Find more information about an Event Reciver

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I am trying to debug a customized SharePoint 2010 which I did not design/install.

It is not doing what it is suppose to when a list item is added.

I have installed SharePoint Manager, and found the event receiver that is suppose to be fired for when a list item is added.

However it doesn't tell me much, it doesn't seeem to be custom code.

It has Assembly:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
```

and class:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver
```

How can I find out more information about this event reciever and what it is suppose to do?

Where would the files etc. be for it? I'm not sure where I can even start to try and debug it. There are no error logs in the SharePointlog files.

Comment: This truly is an OOTB event receiver, what is supposed to happen when you add a list item?

Comment: Im not 100% sure what is suppose to happen (either is the client). The end result the list item will get edited (not sure what part gets edited) then a custom event receiver is fired.. I dont know why the custom event reciever isnt just set to item added rather than item updated. but I need to find out what this receiver does before I go and change anything

Comment: Well the event reciever you mention above is just responsible for kicking of any associated workflows

Comment: yes that was my first assumption but that are no workflows attached..

Comment: The event receiver is still there, but will not find any workflows to kickoff, so it should not be a problem

Comment: The site receives information from a submitted infopath form. then ?? then the custom itemadded event receiver fires and does its work.. I have looked at a restored server that doesnt have a workflow attached but it still somehow fires the itemupdated event
 receiver and works